# Django Race Condition when increment use table inside form_valid

Tags: django, race-condition

I am using class based views. I am trying to increment a value everytime user create a new record.

```
#models.py
class User(models.Model)
    transaction_counter = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=1, # +1 when new transaction created
    )

class Transaction(models.Model)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField() # base on the user.transaction_counter

#views.py
class TransactionCreate(CreateView):
model = Transaction

@transaction.atomic
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.number = self.request.user.transaction_counter  # just assign the number
    self.request.user.transaction_counter= F('transaction_counter') + 1
    self.request.user.save()  # now we +1 for the next transaction
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

## Question

Since I already use F() to increment the user.transaction_counter, does this solve the race condition issue? If no, please guide me on this. If yes Thank you & Love you.

Comment: Yes using F() will resolve the race condition., but make sure to call `self.request.user.refresh_from_db(fields=['transaction_counter'])` after `self.request.user.save()`

Comment: oh ya thanks for pointing out the important step am missing out. Otherwise the next save will increment again am i right @HariHaraSudhan. THanks <3

Comment: yes., passing `fields`  to refresh_from_db is optional as well.